# Computing variables before each iteration using the DataSet API in Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am working with the clustering example provided with Flink ([Kmeans](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-batch/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/examples/java/clustering/KMeans.java)) and trying to extend the functionality of it. The goal is to reduce the number of distance computations by computing a multidimensional-array consisting of the distances between each centroid, such that the distances can be found in a `double[][]` array. This array must be computed at the beginning of each iteration and broadcasted, when the points are assigned clusters.

I have tried the following:

```
public static final class computeCentroidInterDistance implements MapFunction<Tuple2<Centroid, Centroid>, Tuple3<Integer, Integer, Double>> {

    @Override
    public Tuple3<Integer, Integer, Double> map(Tuple2<Centroid, Centroid> centroid) throws Exception {
        return new Tuple3<>(centroid.f0.id, centroid.f1.id, centroid.f0.euclideanDistance(centroid.f1));
    }
}

DataSet<Centroid> centroids = getCentroidDataSet(..);

DataSet<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, Double>> distances = centroids
    .crossWithTiny(centroids)
    .map(new computeCentroidInterDistance());
```

However, I dont see how the distances DataSet can be used for my use-case as this is not returned in any specific order that can be used to lookup the distances between two different centroids. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataSets are inherently unordered and sharded, both which are not suited for your use case.

What you want to do is to first collect all centroids in one method invocation.

```
DataSet<double[][]> matrix = centroids.reduceGroup(...)
```

Within the reduceGroup you have access to all elements and you can perform the calculation. The output should be your double[][] matrix.

The matrix can then be distributed with a [broadcast](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/#broadcast-variables).

Comment: Thank you for guiding me in the right direction! This solution worked perfectly, I only had to ensure that the centroids was in the same order for each iteration in the iterable in the reduce function.